# Unity game Sqlite database acts different when running on Android Device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have implemented an SQLite database on my unity project and It works perfectly on unity editor. But when I run it on android device database operations act weird.

It has a main menu which user can select each one of 4 games and play them.
I'm calculating the total time that user spends on a game. So I added a timer on each game and pushed the timer count into the database then when the user hits back it calculates the sum of total time.

In Unity editor, it perfectly shows the last added total time on the main menu.
but in android, when user come back to the main menu the total time gets to rest. It doesn't perform the sum operation on android.

But when I perform the operation within the same scene it works on Android as well.

I've done everything correctly when compiling SQLite for android. I've added my DB file into StreamingAssets and Added all necessary plugins.

Here are my code and file structure.

[image]

Timer.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;

    private string connectionString;

    string minutes;
    string seconds;
    string a;
    float t;

    float DailyTime;

    string CurrentDate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite";
        //  // if it doesn't ->

        //  // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->

        WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite");  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android

        while(!loadDB.isDone) {}  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check
        //  // then save to Application.persistentDataPath

        File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDB.bytes);
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + filepath;
        //connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath +  "/StreamingAssets/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite";

        startTime = Time.time;



        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        CurrentDate = PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        t = Time.time - startTime;

        //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("RowTime",t);

        minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString ();
        seconds = (t % 60).ToString ("f0");


        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("TimeKey", minutes + ":" + seconds);
        timerText.text =PlayerPrefs.GetString("TimeKey");
        a = minutes;
    }

    public void AddEvent(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO events(date,timer_count) VALUES({0},{1})",System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),t);
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time"));
    }

    public void GetSum(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT SUM(timer_count) FROM events WHERE date={0}",CurrentDate);
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                    while (reader.Read ()) {
                        DailyTime = reader.GetFloat (0);
                    }

                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close ();
                }


            }
        }

    }

    public void AddDailyEvent(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("UPDATE daily_events SET timer_count={0} WHERE date={1}",DailyTime,CurrentDate);
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SetDateRow.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class SetDateRow : MonoBehaviour {

    private string connectionString;

    string SqliteDailyDate;
    string SqliteEventsDate;
    float TheTime;

    string CurrentDate;

    public Text DataText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite";
        //  // if it doesn't ->

        //  // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->

        WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite");  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android

        while(!loadDB.isDone) {}  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check
        //  // then save to Application.persistentDataPath

        File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDB.bytes);
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + filepath;
        //connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath +  "/StreamingAssets/" + "trackerDB2.sqlite";


        AddEvent ();
        AddFirstEvent ();

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        CurrentDate = PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    //  GetEvent ();
    }

    //Add new event with o timer at the start of the game
    public void AddEvent(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO events(date,timer_count) VALUES({0},0)",System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time"));
    }

    //get the last added date of events from daily events table which has the total sum of the time that user played each game
    public void GetDateDailyEvents(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT date FROM daily_events ORDER BY eventID DESC LIMIT 1");
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                    while (reader.Read ()) {
                        SqliteDailyDate = reader.GetString (0);
                    }

                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close ();
                }


            }
        }
    }


    //get the last added date from events table which has timer count of each event seperately
    public void GetDateEvents(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT date FROM events ORDER BY event_id DESC LIMIT 1");
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                    while (reader.Read ()) {
                        SqliteEventsDate = reader.GetString (0);
                    }

                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close ();
                }


            }
        }
    }


    public void AddFirstEvent(){
        GetDateDailyEvents ();
        GetDateEvents ();
        Debug.Log ("daily" + SqliteDailyDate);
        Debug.Log (SqliteEventsDate);
        //check if the last date of events table is equal to the last date of daily events table.
        if (SqliteDailyDate != SqliteEventsDate) {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection (connectionString)) {
                dbConnection.Open ();
                //if not equal a new event to daily events table will be added
                using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand ()) {
                    string sqlQuery = String.Format ("INSERT INTO daily_events(date,timer_count) VALUES({0},0)", System.DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                    dbCmd.ExecuteScalar ();
                    dbConnection.Close ();
                }
            }

        }


        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time"));
    }

    public void ShowData(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT timer_count FROM daily_events WHERE date={0}",SqliteDailyDate);
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                    while (reader.Read ()) {
                        DataText.text = reader.GetFloat (0).ToString();
                    }

                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close ();
                }


            }
        }
    }


    public void GetEvent(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT timer_count FROM daily_events WHERE date={0}",CurrentDate);
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                    while (reader.Read ()) {
                        DataText.text = reader.GetFloat (0).ToString();
                    }

                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close ();
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are rewriting your database each time on start.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDB.bytes);
```

I propose to add check if DB file already exist do not rewrite it.

Comment: I added a checking condition and it worked. Thankyou so much.!!